# Is there any indication throughout history that technological progression will end?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, technology

Bernard Stiegler argued that technics was a form of memory and was always progressing. Yet, philosophy isn’t the right thing to rely on when dealing with science. Science doesn’t have a mind and technology doesn’t have a mind in reality. I know about Moore’s Law but are there any other scientists who have found some proof in speculating that technological progression is infinite?

Comment: Moore's law is of a kind with the [Malthusian catastrophe from 1798](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malthusianism), the [horse manure crisis of 1894](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_horse_manure_crisis_of_1894) and the [The Limits to Growth by the Club of Rome from 1972](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Limits_to_Growth). Alas, such sorts of simplistic extrapolations are more indicative of lack of imagination than of technological limitations. As always with attempted clairvoyance, one is better off with vague analogies *a la* Stiegler, but this is not the right site to get into them.

Comment: It is simply not true that "that technics was a form of memory and was always progressing". We have at least two cases in European history of "collapse of civilization", when regress happened for several hundreds of years.

Comment: Condorcet might have been the first to have offered some "proof" ; he is also credited as having suggested the idea of "Technological Singularity"; see the wikipedia article and also https://ojs.aaai.org/index.php/aimagazine/article/view/2855